# ASP.NET Core 1 app migrate to custom OWIN server

Tags: asp.net-core, owin

I know that `asp.net core 1` application supports `OWIN` specification.So how can i migrate an application to my own custom web server where i will implement catching of `http` requests and creation of `OWIN` dictionary manually ?

Comment: Have you seen this sample? https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/dev/samples/Owin.Nowin.HelloWorld

Answer (score 1):

you should implement owin pipeline beside asp.net core, it's not as an alternative
these two architecture can work beside together properly.
implementation of owin pipeline let you to use tools have not released in asp.net core such as OData, Thinktecture Identity server, ...
you can read this article to implement Owin pipeline
[Implement Owin pipeline using Asp.net core](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1122162/Implement-Owin-Pipeline-using-Asp-net-Core)

and you can download codes using [Github](https://github.com/Alikhll/OwinAspNetCore)